# Decorator pattern for a Customer class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

Suppose I have a `Customer` class. A customer can have multiple kinds of loyalty points. For one promotion, the customer may be collecting `Rewards`. In another, the customer may be collecting `Miles`. And there is no fixed number of kinds of loyalty points that the `Customer` is built for. I am sure this is a common use case. Is the decorator pattern a good fit given below sample code?

```
    public interface ICustomer
    {
        void Display();
    }

    public class SimpleCustomer : ICustomer
    {
        public void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am simple customer");
        }
    }

    public abstract class CustomerDecorator : ICustomer
    {
        protected ICustomer customer;

        public CustomerDecorator(ICustomer customer)
        {
            this.customer = customer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("customer");
        }

        public abstract void Display();
    }

    public class RewardsDecorator : CustomerDecorator
    {
        private int rewards;
        public RewardsDecorator(ICustomer customer, int rewards) : base(customer)
        {
            this.rewards = rewards;
        }

        public override void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Now I have " + rewards.ToString() + " rewards");
        }
    }

    public class MilesDecorator : CustomerDecorator
    {
        private int miles;
        public MilesDecorator(ICustomer customer, int miles) : base(customer)
        {
            this.miles = miles;
        }

        public override void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Now I have " + miles.ToString() + " miles");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think Decorator pattern does what you want it to do. Decorator adds new functionalities on top of the original class. A typical wiki example would say, we can add scroll bar, menu bar, overlays and other UI components on top of canvas. So to make a proper browser window, so you will have:

```
public class Canvas
public class ScrollableCanvas
public class OverlayedCanvas
etc.
```

So that we add more functionalities to the original Canvas.

To solve your problem, you should have something like:

```
public abstract class LoyaltyProgramAccount {...}

public class RewardAccount extends LoyaltyProgramAccount {...}

public class MilesAccount extends LoyaltyProgramAccount {...}
```

And then add a registery-ish enum:

```
public enum LoyaltyProgramTypes {
    miles,
    reward,
}
```

and then let user be:

```
public class Customer {

    private List<LoyaltyProgramTypes, LoyaltyProgramAccount> accounts;

    public void openAccount(LoyaltyProgramTypes type, LoyaltyProgramAccount account) {
        accounts.put(type, account);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that Decorator is the pattern you are looking for.

Besides, your code does not seem to be an implementation of the Decorator pattern. You do not add any functionality to the only function. You just override it. But adding to the existing function is what the Decorator pattern is all about.

My approach would be state / strategy pattern. There are different kinds of rewards. And a customer has one or more of them. These rewards may share a common interface and provide different implementations. The customer (or a subclass or compound object `RewardedCustomer`) should hold a list or map of these rewards.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the visitor pattern, this is pretty ideal for your situation. This will allow you nicely separate the rewards calculations for you different customer types and run operations against all supported rewards types.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MilesCustomer customer = new MilesCustomer();
        ICustomerVisitor<int> visitor = new MilesCalculation(10);
        var miles = customer.Visit(visitor);
        visitor = new RewardsCalucation(100);
        var rewards = customer.Visit(visitor);
    }
}
public interface ICustomerVisitor<T>
{
    T Visit(SimpleCustomer cusomter);
    T Visit(RewardsCustomer cusomter);
    T Visit(MilesCustomer cusomter);
}

public abstract class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        TotalMoneySpent = 10;
    }

    public int TotalMoneySpent { get; private set; }

    public abstract T Visit<T>(ICustomerVisitor<T> visitor);

    public virtual void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am simple customer");
    }
}

public class RewardsCalucation : ICustomerVisitor<int>
{
    private int _rewardsPerDollar;

    public RewardsCalucation(int rewardsPerDollar) => _rewardsPerDollar = rewardsPerDollar;

    public int Visit(SimpleCustomer cusomter)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public int Visit(RewardsCustomer cusomter)
    {
        return cusomter.TotalMoneySpent * _rewardsPerDollar;
    }

    public int Visit(MilesCustomer cusomter)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class MilesCalculation : ICustomerVisitor<int>
{
    private int _milesPerDollar;
    public MilesCalculation(int milesPerDollar) => _milesPerDollar = milesPerDollar;
    public int Visit(SimpleCustomer cusomter)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public int Visit(RewardsCustomer cusomter)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public int Visit(MilesCustomer cusomter)
    {
        return cusomter.TotalMoneySpent * _milesPerDollar;
    }
}

public class SimpleCustomer : Customer
{
    public override T Visit<T>(ICustomerVisitor<T> visitor)
    {
        return visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

public class RewardsCustomer : Customer
{
    public override T Visit<T>(ICustomerVisitor<T> visitor)
    {
        return visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

public class MilesCustomer : Customer
{
    public override T Visit<T>(ICustomerVisitor<T> visitor)
    {
        return visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
```